# GridView DropDownList, handling null values

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I realize variations of this question have been asked and I've dutifully researched dozens them here and elsewhere, but so far I can't come to a solution. Hopefully I'm just missing something and someone in this fine community can help me out. I've read and tried the [Handling Null Data in Data Source Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366709.aspx/%20%22Handling%20Null%20Data%20Using%20Data%20Source%20Controls) MSDN article, but also no luck.

Here's my situation. I'm using EntityDataSource and a SQL Server database (if that matters) and I have a main table (lets call it Shipments) which references various child tables via foreign key. For example, the Shipment table points has a Truck column which references the Truck table.

A Truck is not required at the time a Shipment is created. If a user later edits a Shipment to add a Truck, everything works fine. This is done via a DropDownList within a GridView template field, like so (I'm sorry, I don't know how to format this prettily - I'll edit the post later if I can):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTrucks" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        DataTextField="Number" DataValueField="TruckID" DataSourceID="esrcTrucks"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TruckID") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="(Select)"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Okay, so in the case where a Truck was not entered during Shipment creation (common), the DropDownList populates nicely with "(Select)" as the selected item.

HOWEVER, if a Shipment references a Truck, and that Truck is later deleted (lets say it wrecked and is no longer part of the fleet), that's where I run into issues and get a "ddlTruck has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value" error message.

Preferably, I'd like to head off this exception so it doesn't happen at all. If I must, though, is there a way of catching this exception and "fixing" the DDL so the page can be displayed and the user can go about their way? How/where would I catch this? So, I suppose my questions are:

- Is this a database design issue? Should a Delete of a referenced
  entity be handled in some way that I'm not doing currently?
- Is there    a way of preventing this exception from happening at all,
  like it does when no Truck has ever been entered (DDL just displays
  "(Select)")?
- If I need to catch and handle this exception, how or where would I do
  so?

Just to clarify, it is **not** a requirement for the DDL to retain data from the deleted truck. Simply displaying "Select", an empty string, or any default value would be fine. The intent is that this should not crash the page, and a user should be able to go about editing other details of the shipment if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent a couple days on this and haven't been able to get anything to work! If I can provide more information or if I have been unclear in my post, please let me know.

Thanks so much!

Comment: So does the shipment need to retain the value of the truck that no longer exists or should it be updated?  I'm assuming that you want the page to load and then the user will update that DDL with a currently valid choice?  Is this correct?

Comment: It is not a requirement that the GridView/page retain the previous value. Displaying an empty string or some other default value would be fine, as this is not a required field (either in the GridView or the database table itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thankfully continued searching found a solution. Since I was having such trouble catching this exception via GridView events, I instead created my own DropDownList WebControl. I then overrode the **PerformDataBinding** event. Here's the general idea:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyDropDownList runat=server></{0}:MyDropDownList>")]
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{

    protected override void PerformDataBinding(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource)
    {
        try
        {
            base.PerformDataBinding(dataSource);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            // Handled the exception here
        }

    }
}
```

This solution was found on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296018/problem-with-gridview-bind-and-dropdownlist?rq=1). The community on this site has saved me some serious ulcers. Thanks so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the SelectedValue in the tag in the front end, try checking the validity of TruckID in the Page_Load of the code behind file and set selected value there.

For instance, here I'll check if TruckID is not Null.  If it has a value then I set the selected value to TruckID, otherwise, I'll set the selected value to the first item in ddlTrucks assuming the first item is a default selection.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        ddlTrucks.SelectedValue = TruckID != Null ? TruckID : ddlTrucks.Items[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The DropDownLists are part of a GridView's Edit template, as such I don't think it will have any value at Page_Load() since the control will not exist at that time? I've been trying to find a good event on GridView to jump in to do such a check, but so far the events have either been too early (RowEditing - control not populated yet) or I get the exception before the event is run (Row DataBound).